# Z-matrix multiplied by its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, transpose

What can be said about eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $ZZ^T$ if Z is a Z-matrix whose columns sum to zero?

Comment: Not much can be said: the eigenvalues of $ZZ^T$ are nonnegative; at least one of the eigenvalues is zero and the all-one vector is a corresponding eigenvector.